# App wont open below lollipop versions

Tags: android

I am new to android development,
i have made one app which is working perfect on 5.0 and above. but when i tasted .apk with my other phone which is runnnig on micromax 4.4.2 os( 480x800) mobile, it installs but doesnt open. unfortunately app_name has been stop.
so i attatchd my microamx mobile to android studio and tried to run app. everything workd well. why it doesnt work when i shared .apk before??
please help.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kalpu.practice1234"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Comment: you are getting some error in your first activity try to see it using logcat

Comment: just need to off instant run from android studio then clean and rebuild project.

Comment: turn off instant run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by **Instant Run**. It is not the problem of gradle.

[Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run) will generate the .apk for a specific device and if you use the same .apk for another device it will not work.

If you want to run the same .apk on another device then disable Instant Run and build.

Answer (score 1):

Try below things:

Turn off Instant run from android studio like below.

Then clean project and rebuild it.

Then Run it.

If still you getting problem then post your logcat error.

[image: Turn off Instant Run]

Comment: @kalps if its helpful then don't forget to accept as answer dear.

Comment: sry..didnt knw that too..new Dev

Answer (score 0):

1. I wouldn't turn off a useful feature (Instant run)
2. Generating the signed version just for this can be overkill, especially if it's a new project that hasn't been signed yet.

Simply use the **Build APK** menu item from the **Build** menu.

[image]

You will get a small popup with a link to open the generated APK in the file manager:

[image]

Note: the screenshots are taken in Android Studio 2.2 running in Windows 10.

Comment: i tried buiding sign .apk. but now its not installing on my marshmallow mobile. :(

Comment: @kalps You can try uninstalling your app from your mobile first: open the Settings app from your phone and select your app from _Apps_ or _Manage Apps_.